# How do you create a wifi hotspot with network drive

Tags: shared-folders, hot-spot

How can I make a hotspot with a shared folder throughout the lan, such as done by USB port on the back of some routers?

Comment: These are 2 separate questions. After you make a hot spot, the shared folder need to configured on a server. If you are using Windows, share a directory. If you are using windows, use samba. The shared folder you are asking about on most routers is a built in samba server.